# SQLmap finds injectable 'id' parameter but the response is 'Internal Server Error'

Tags: penetration-test, sql-injection, sqlmap

I am trying to understand the SQLi so I ran SQLMap with '-vvv' parameter

> 4: Show also HTTP requests.

I did scan one of the vulnerable and 'free to hack' sites.
In one of the requests sent, the response from SQLmap was:

> [22:25:10] [DEBUG] got HTTP error code: 500 ('Internal Server Error')
>
> [22:25:10] [INFO] GET parameter 'id' appears to be 'AND boolean-based
> blind - WHERE or HAVING clause' injectable (with --code=200)

I tried to use same payload
`GET /showforum.asp?id=1%20AND%20%28SELECT%20CHR%28116%29%7C%7CCHR%28100%29%7C%7CCHR%2885%29%7C%7CCHR%28111%29%20FROM%20SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1%29%3D%27tdUo%27` in Burp but it keeps throwing me 500 error.

Can someone explain me how did excatly SQLmap come to this conclusion that parameter ID is injectable, while there was an error?
I tried to compare different 500 error responses, but no difference between this specific payload ant other ones.

Any answer will be appreciated,
thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What makes a SQL Injection count as blind injection?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/37121/what-makes-a-sql-injection-count-as-blind-injection)

Comment: The linked question may not be an exact answer to your question, but I think you'll get most of what you need there.  Blind SQLi is when you don't get a detailed response from the application but infer that SQLi is happening because of changes in the response otherwise - often just a change of status code.  Also see this: https://owasp.org/www-community/attacks/Blind_SQL_Injection

Comment: The problem is nothing changed in status code, I mean the response is same for:
`GET /showforum.asp?id=1%20AND%20%28SELECT%20CHR%28116%29%7C%7CCHR%28100%29%7C%7CCHR%2885%29%7C%7CCHR%28111%29%20FROM%20SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1%29%3D%27tdUo%27` and same for `GET /showforum.asp?id=1%20AND%203246%3D7682 HTTP/1.1` but SQLMap points the first one as 'found injectable...', and that's what I really don't understand. I mean for me there is no difference in the response

Comment: Presumably when you don't have any payload you get a 200, not a 500.  That would be the "blind boolean" part.  All the system tells you is that if you do try to inject a payload you get a 500, instead of 200.  Getting data out in such a scenario is difficult and may be impossible, but typically if you get a 200 for a normal request and then a 500 for a request with an SQLi payload, that's a sign that it may be vulnerable.

Comment: Still lot's of questions but it's a bit brighter now, thanks!

Answer (score -1):

500  Internal Error means that the SQLmap's payload is being detected and cannot fully exploit the target.  You  can try with option --random-agent and/or --hex maybe this will successfully do it.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer, I don't really want to exploit the database more, I just want to understand why from two payloads, which both resulted in the very same (byte by byte, word by word) response, one of them was marked as 'injectable' by SQLmap, this is really what I don't understand

Comment: SQLmap first checks for the response, for example it will respond with MYSQL error, then sqlmap marks it as injectable, so it is possible that sqlmap just marks it as injectable  but whenever you try to inject any payload to determine tables and any other information it will be blocked.

Comment: Oh I see, now it makes sense, thank you